# In a Data Validation list in excel, can I have both text and a cell reference as its options?

Tags: excel

I want a data validation list where I have have the following options:

"Custom"

and...

Cell Range A1:A200

Is it possible to have both text and a cell range in a data validation list?

Comment: What if you make A1 "Custom", then move your data down. Would that work?

Comment: @BruceWayne I want my drop down list to show "Custom" as the first option, after that I want a range of cells from another sheet as the rest of the drop down list options - I would have done that but i'm not able to due to the range of cells being ID numbers and custom is not a proper ID

Comment: Hm, I think your issue is more "Can I use multiple ranges as a data validation list" than mixing types.  I tried doing `=A1,B1:B10` and you can't.  What I think you'll need to do is just add "Custom" to the top of your list, then use the new range. ...ie `A1:A201` where `A1` is "Custom".

Comment: @BruceWayne Yeah, its looking that way, it seems like something simple that excel should do because I know you can just manual type a list and separate with commas and I know you can choose a range so a mix of both doesn't seem too farfetched, I may put "custom" in my list but then hide that particular row so nobody can see it, thanks